# Can the limit $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x + h) - 2f(x) + f(x - h)}{h^2}$ exist if $f'(x)$ does not exist at $x$?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

The second derivative of $f$ can be written as

$$f''(x) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x + h) - 2f(x) + f(x - h)}{h^2}$$

while it can also be written as (in fact, I believe this is the definition of $f''(x)$):

$$f''(x) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f'(x + h) - f'(x)}{h}$$

From the second expression, it seems clear that if $f'(x)$ does not exist, then $f''(x)$ cannot exist as well.

However, the first expression does not involve $f'(x)$, so this got me wondering: If $f'(x)$ does not exist at $x$ , can the limit $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x + h) - 2f(x) + f(x - h)}{h^2}$ at $x$  exist?

How would one prove/disprove this? If this were to be true, what would be some examples?

Comment: No. There is no skipping over derivatives. You just need to use the condition you have to show that the difference quotient limit for the first derivative exists.

Comment: I'd rephrase this question as "Can the limit $\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)}{h^2}$ exist if $f'$ does not exist at $x$" or something similar, because the limit is not the definition of $f''$. With standard notation, $f''$ can't exist if $f'$ does not.

Comment: @JiK You are right, thanks!

Comment: The limit of $(f(x+2h) - 2f(x+h) + f(x))/h^2$ is also worth considering.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first limit can exist even though the second does not, but this is not the *definition* of $f^{\prime\prime}$. *By definition, $f^{\prime\prime}$ can only be defined if $f^{\prime}$ is.*

However, for the limits, consider
$$
f\colon x\in\mathbb{R}\mapsto \begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } x < 0 \\
1 & \text{ if } x = 0 \\
2 & \text{ if } x > 0
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 6):

An easy counterexample is the case of an odd function that's not differentiable at $0$: let $f$ be any odd function (defined at $0$). Then:
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(0-h)-2f(0)+f(0+h)}{h^2}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(-h)+f(h)}{h^2}=0.$$
So there are lots of counterexample, e.g., $f(x)=x^{1/3}$.